# Blob equation in $\Bbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, examples-counterexamples

I'll start by apologizing for the nature of my request. I'm not sure if this kind of post fits exactly what is expected of the forum, but at the same time I can't think of a more suitable place.

I'm looking for a blob around a sphere that looks good in a presentation. The blob should be the image of a smooth function $\phi:S^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$ such that $\forall p\in S^2~\exists \lambda\in\Bbb{R}_{>1}~\phi(p) = \lambda p$ (purely for aesthetic reasons). A sphere or an ellipse would do, but I'd like something that sounds less biased. Something more like an amoeba.

At the presentation, it will be semi-transparent, so you can see the sphere inside it, and I intend to plot it with the help of Geogebra. It should look something like the image below.

[image: caption]

Comment: You want something wobbly looking to replace the blue sphere?

Comment: @Paul that's right.

Comment: Using spherical coordinates with longitude $\theta$ and latitude $\phi$, you can pick an arbitrary function $\rho$ with period $2\pi$ in $\theta$ and period $\pi$ in $\phi$, and then plot the spherical graph$$(x,y,z)=\rho(\theta,\phi)(\cos\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\phi).$$

Comment: A [metaball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs), perhaps, consisting of say half a dozen seed points and weights to determine the shape?